# Rails Install Fails Due To Invalid Option: --include-dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

Trying to install rails on a new Mac I just got.  I enter:

```
sudo gem install rails --include-dependencies
```

But it produces:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
invalid option: --include-dependencies
```

If I run it without the include dependencies, I get other errors that seem to be related to dependencies.  Why would this option not work for me but it does others?  Is there another option I can include which will instal all the dependencies?

Note: I'm new to Linux/Mac/Rails/Gems, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think --include-dependencies is the default now so no need to use it and is in fact deprecated (and in your case removed).

From the release notes for rubygems 0.9.5 http://blog.rubygems.org/2007/11/19/0.9.5-released.html:

> gem install --include-dependencies (-y) is now deprecated since it is
>   the default, use –ignore-dependencies to turn off automatic dependency
>   installation

Comment: Weird cause I had to install a bunch of other things before I eventually got it to work without the --include-dependencies.  But it's working now.  Thanks